# Translating a sequence of functions from the interval $[0,1] $ to the interval $[a,b].$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

For the interval $[0,1],$ define $f_n(x)=n(\frac  1 n-x) $ for $0 \leq x\leq \frac  1n$ and $f_n(x)=0$ for $x> \frac 1 n$. Then the maximum norm  tends to 1 but the $\|{f}\|_{1} = (1/2n)$ norm  tends to zero.

Now, Transforming this example to be on the interval $[a,b].$ define $g_n(x)=f_n(\frac  {x-a} {b-a})$ for  $0 \leq \frac  {x-a} {b-a}\leq \frac  1n$ and $g_n(x) = f_n(x)=0$ for $\frac  {x-a} {b-a} > \frac {1}{n}.$

But I was told that the maximum norm of the new function $g_{n}$ is still 1 (which I do not understand how )and $\|{g}\|_{1}$ norm equals  $((b - a)/2n)$ (which also I do not understand how )  , could anyone show me the details of the calculations please?

Note: $\| f\| _{1} =\int_{a}^{b} | f|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{f_n(x): 0 \leq x \leq 1\}=\{g_n(y): a \leq y \leq b\}$ because $a \leq y \leq b$ iff $0 \leq \frac {y-a} {b-a} \leq 1$. Take sup on both sides to to get the first result.

$\int_a^{b} |g_n(y)|dy=\int_a^{b} |f_n(\frac {y-a} {b-a})|dy$. Make the the change of variables $x =\frac {y-a} {b-a}$. [ Note that $dy=(b-a)dx$]. Hence $\int_a^{b} |g_n(y)|dy=\frac {b-a} {2n}$.

Comment: by what you said in your answer is this definition $g_n(x)=f_n(\frac  {x-a} {b-a})$  still correct? are the x and y in the right place?

Comment: your interchanging use for $x$ and $y$ is confusing me

Comment: Perhaps $x$ and $y$ got switched from your previous question. But the correct definition of $g_n$ is $g_n(x)=f_n(\frac {x-a} {b-a})$ for  all $x$ in $[a,b]$. There is no point in writing out  $g_n(x)$ in different sub-intervals of $[a,b]$ as far as this question is concerned. You will unnecessarily make this complicated by considering whether $\frac {x-a} {b-a}$ is less than  or greater than $\frac  1 n$.

Comment: in your answer here when you said $g_{n}(y)$ what is $y$?

Comment: $y$ is a point in $[a,b]$.

Comment: Can you do "the change of variables"  and "the taking sup of both sides" in details ,,,, I really got confused